# How to prevent entering numbers in Flutter TextFormField?

Tags: flutter

I am developing an application with Flutter. I put `TextFormField`. I want to prevent entering numbers in this `TextFormField`. How can I do that?

Comment: On what platforms does your app run (iOS, Android, browser, macOS etc) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextFormField(
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('[0-9]')),
  ], 
),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `validator` argument to create a callback if the user input a number.
You can also add the `keyboardType` argument to limit the user to only text with the value `TextInputType.text`

Answer (score 1):

```
   inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp("[0-9]")),
                    ],
```

You need to add this